# javascript modules export updated variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm new to js modules and I don't fully understand how they works, my problem is;

I have this `fixed` var that I need in more modules so at the moment my code is:

```
let fixed

const getFixed = () => {
  return $.getJSON('data/fixed.json')
    .done((data) => {
      fixed = data.settings[0]
    })
    .fail((jqxhr, textStatus, error) => {
      const err = `${textStatus} , ${error}`
      alert(`fixed.json for getSettings Request Failed: ${err}`)
    })
}

const init = () => {
  return getFixed()
}

const getFixedSettings = () => {
  return fixed
}

export default {
  init,
  getFixedSettings
}
```

and in my app, it's another module, I do:

```
import functions from './functions'

const initialize = () => {
  // update the settings
  functions.init()
// initialize the map
.then(() => mapInit(functions.getFixedSettings()))
}
```

but when I ask for `functions.getFixedSettings()` in another module I need to call again `functions.init()` before to have the updated var

What is the correct way to export that updated `fixed` var and be accessible to all my modules?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `fixed` to bet accessible to all modules, you could just be exporting `fixed`: `export let fixed`.

Comment: yes but as you can see the `fixed` is populate after the `ajax` request, that is my problem

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have the fixed var populate once then use it anywhere?

Comment: yes, because at the moment i need to call `functions.init()` and then I can use `functions.getFixedSettings()` my code is actually working now but in every module I need to run `functions.init()` and then I can use `functions.getFixedSettings()`

Comment: Write a general class in which his role is to execute functions.init() once than store the result in a property accessible anywhere in your code.